# How to predict new raster using model generated by cforest

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

I use randomForest model to predict class memberships. 'x' consists of 10 classes that I use to train 'training_predictors' values extracted from a large rasterstack/brick. The specific line of codes is:

> r_tree<-randomForest(x ~. , data=training_predictors, ...)

Then I run 'predict' using the model 'r_tree' that I apply to the rasterstack 'predictor_data', as follow:

> predictions<-predict(predictor_data, r_tree, filename=outraster, fun=predict na.rm=TRUE, format="PCDISK", overwrite=TRUE, progress="text", type="response").

The output is a raster that I use as thematic map.

I would like to use the conditional inference trees mode 'cforest' instead of randomForest to achieve the same goals.

I understand that 'predict' can be used with cforest, yet, I have not been able to generate raster files, such as those with randomForest as illustrated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should run fine, but you may need to add the argument OOB=TRUE, and identify factors if there are any.

Example data

```
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)

a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)

# extract values for points
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
v <- data.frame(cbind(xy[,1], extract(logo, xy[,2:3])))
colnames(v)[1] <- 'pa'
```

Basic model

```
library(party)
m1 <- cforest(pa~., control=cforest_unbiased(mtry=3), data=v)
pc1 <- predict(logo, m1, OOB=TRUE)
plot(pc1)
```

Model with factors

```
v$red <- as.factor(round(v$red/100))
logo$red <- round(logo[[1]]/100)
m2 <- cforest(pa~., control=cforest_unbiased(mtry=3), data=v)
f <- list(levels(v$red))
names(f) <- 'red'
pc2 <- predict(logo, m2, OOB=TRUE, factors=f)
plot(pc2)
```

By the way, this comes almost straight out of the help file of raster::predict

Comment: Hi, thanks, but no success. I can run edit using a randomForest model with a 'Large RasterStack' ~500million elements large, but when I try with a cforest model (basic) it appears to be working but no result after few hours waiting.. with the same data, except that cforest requires a data.frame. Puzzling indeed. Pierre

Comment: Well, the above shows that it should work. If it does not work for you, that could be for several reasons. Set up a very small example first, for a few cells only, and try to run it first as a data.frame (data.frame(  s[1:10] ) (unless the first 10 cells are NA), then for a small Raster (  s[1:10, drop=FALSE] )

Comment: Yes, I had the same thought. I ran a test with a 100×100 raster file and I it took about 10 min for 'predict' to finish. The original raster is 2445×2852 (with ~75 variables/layers). When using a Random Forest object, it takes about 40 min to complete. Well, if cforest model prediction rate is correct, it would take nearly 5 days to get a full raster. This is rather puzzling. Many thanks.